# Selecting multiple columns in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have searched the web for this and came up short.. I am using this VBA to select a column based on the column header. What I want to do is also select the 3 columns to the right of the one i've currently got selected. Either that or have this VBA loop through more than 1 column header.

```
    Sub selectingcolumnstest()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgUni As Range
Dim xFirstAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "ColumnNameHere"
    Set xRg = Range("A1:CD1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A1:CD1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select



End Sub
```

There are 3 additional columns to the right of "ColumnNameHere" that I also want to select.. (I am going to delete these columns). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim xStr As String, hdr as variant

xStr = "ColumnNameHere"

hdr = application.match(xStr, Range("A1:CD1"), 0)

if not iserror(hdr) then
    cells(1, hdr).resize(1, 4).entirecolumn.select
    'cells(1, hdr).resize(1, 4).entirecolumn.delete
end if
```

Comment: This works great, and it is much shorter and easier to understand. I appreciate the quick response!